# how to handle postrm error when removing debian package

Tags: debian-jessie

Having tried to install jitsi package on jessie debian, I decided to remove this installation.Removing videobridge, jicofo, meet-prosody run fine. But attempting to remove jitsi-meet-tokens package, I got error msg on console.

I've tried removing through apt-get purge and got the following answer on console :

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  jitsi-meet-tokens
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 1 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 54,3 ko d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
(Lecture de la base de données... 224456 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de jitsi-meet-tokens (1.0.1073-1) ...
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet jitsi-meet-tokens (--remove) :
 le sous-processus script post-removal installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 10
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 jitsi-meet-tokens
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
```

I've tried through `dpkg -P jitsi-meet-tokens` but I got the same error message.

Moreover, when trying to install new packages (`apt-get autoclean then apt-get update` and finally `apt-get install package_name`), the system first attempts to remove the jitsi stuff and gives me the same error message.

Anyone can help ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

quick dirty fix:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/jitsi-meet-tokens.postrm
```

Comment: Sorry no such file in this directory.

Comment: Sorry Problem fixed. In fact the jitsi postrm stuff are hidden files in /var/lib/dpkg/info.